# PHP Recursive Function base on single id export excel

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-excel, treegrid, easygui

I have a search page that allow user to key in the member ID and it will list out all the downline that belongs to the user.

I am using easyui treegrid to generate the downline.

Now i need to do an extra button to export out all the downline that belongs to the search id and export each line of information into excel file.

This is part of my data, and actually the real data had more column and about 4000++ of data.

Is there anyone can help me or some references? Please let me know if you need more info

```
+-------------+---------------+---------------------------+------------+
|   MemberID  |   parent_id   |           Name            |    Age     |
+-------------+---------------+---------------------------+------------+
|   1         |       0       |   Cassy                   |     8      |
|   2         |       1       |   Peter                   |     7      |
|   3         |       1       |   Maide                   |     7      |
|   4         |       1       |   Samda                   |     7      |
|   5         |       4       |   Kinso                   |     7      |
|   6         |       4       |   March                   |     7      |
|   7         |       2       |   Sandy                   |     10     |
|   8         |       0       |   Mandy                   |     12     |
+-------+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a community of volunteers offering aid to programmers stuck on a particular task. We are **not** a service to write free code for you. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AlexHowansky Understood. in this case you might as well remove this topic

Comment: Thanks for your understanding. The post will likely be closed as "too broad" shortly.